# pygtk how to replace the contents of a tab on switch-page

Tags: python, pygtk

Suppose i have something like this for a basic notebook:

```py
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import GLib, Gtk


class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="My App")
        self._init = False # Try to stop recursion errors during setup

        self.notebook = Gtk.Notebook()

        self.page0 = Gtk.Label(label='Some text')
        self.page1 = Gtk.Label(label='More text')

        self.notebook.append_page(self.page0, Gtk.Label(label='p1'))
        self.notebook.append_page(self.page1, Gtk.Label(label='p2'))

        self.notebook.connect('switch-page', self.refresh)

        self.add(self.notebook)
        self._init = True


    def refresh(self, notebook, page, page_num):
        if page_num == 0 and self._init:
            self.remove(self.page0)
            self.page0 = Gtk.Label(label='Some more and different text')
            self.notebook.prepend_page(self.page0, Gtk.Label(label='p1'))
            self.notebook.set_current_page(0)

win = MainWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

What I'm trying to do is when the user clicks on the first tab (hence the switch-page signal) that the tab gets "refreshed" (in this case just replacing the text but it could be more substantial change, like changing the Widget being shown). Should I being trying to delete the "old" tab and insert a new one at position 0, or call some function on the tab to update what it shows?

The code as shown crashes with recursion issues (I guess switch-page gets called during setup?), which is why I thought maybe calling some sort of updateWidegt() function would be better than trying to delete a page. But I'm not sure with that how to get the notebook to "see" the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the infinite recursion is that the `switch-page` handler `refresh()`, emits the signal when you are updating the pages. You can avoid that by not changing the pages, but only updating the widgets within the pages, as you mention. I updated your example below:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="My App")
        self.notebook = Gtk.Notebook()
        self.count = 0

        self.page0 = Gtk.Label(label='Some text')
        self.page1 = Gtk.Label(label='More text')

        self.notebook.append_page(self.page0, Gtk.Label(label='p1'))
        self.notebook.append_page(self.page1, Gtk.Label(label='p2'))

        self.notebook.connect('switch-page', self.refresh)

        self.add(self.notebook)

    def refresh(self, notebook, page, page_num):
        self.count += 1
        if page_num == 0:
            self.page0.set_label('Some more and different text {count}'.format(count=self.count))


win = MainWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

If you want to add widgets, let your notebook page be a `Gtk.Box` or another container widget, and add widgets to it. Another way that can be simpler than adding/removing widgets dynamically, is to add all widgets at startup, and simply hide/show them when appropriate.